# php : How to get localities based on ip address

Tags: php

I want to get localities based on IP address in php.

I'm using `geoplugin` for based on IP, I got cities by using this

```
  $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 /*Get user ip address details with geoplugin.net*/
  $geopluginURL='http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$ip_address;
  $addrDetailsArr = unserialize(file_get_contents($geopluginURL)); 
 /*Get City name by return array*/
  $city = $addrDetailsArr['geoplugin_city']; 

 /*Get Country name by return array*/
   $country = $addrDetailsArr['geoplugin_countryName'];
```

Then **how to get locations of the city** in selected field using this

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is related to php and not to Magento

Comment: Yes, this is off-topic.

Comment: Actually in magento  site only i want this functionality using php,so this is not off-topic